# Materialized View or Batched Statements

Tags: cassandra

today i was at the really awesome Cassandra Day in Berlin and, like i hope, there was a small introduction into materialized views. After the talk, i ask Patrick what he prefer and he answered "batched statements" - the reason: data consistency. after a batch the data is definitely written.

My use case is. i've a p.e. a user table (Key: userId) but i create index tables - looking for email, country, etcpp.

In my application, i need to take care of all this "index tables" and it can happend, that someone forget maybe to delete a row in one of this "indices" - after that ... you getting crazy :)

I hoped, that materialized views can help. i've the user table and create multiple materialized views and cassandra take care of the "syncronisation".

So, my question: What do you think about Materialized View or Batched Statements ? Has one of this more benefits as the other ?

Thanks
Marcel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand all the trade-off for Materialized Views, the consistency guarantees are weaker for views than for base table. Read my article : http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=1930

Comment: Wow. This is an awesome and technically deep article. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Materialized views have been created to make it easier to deal with use cases that require many lookup tables. Under the hood, batches are used to apply changes to replicas, so using MVs will also imply using batches. The difference is that you don't have to deal with creating batches yourself. This is not only convenient, but may also prevent bugs from simple programming errors that may occur when you need to update a large number of index tables.

First it might not look much of a big deal to update index tables manually using batches instead of only updating a base table using MVs. But as your application gets bigger and the number of tables and required batches start to grow, introducing schema changes will become harder. You really need to keep track where to update your data and which batches to change. With MVs, all changes to the base table will be propagated automatically to the index tables for you. You can also add new views on top of the base table later, without having to manually populate the index table as you would with batches only.

Coming back to your questions, I'd say yes, materialized views do have benefits over batches.